# How to access the functional component's name from a React hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write a custom React hook, `useLogging`, where I would like to contextualize the log message based upon the name of the component which is doing the logging.

For example:

```
const Login: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props) => {
  log = useLogging();

  log.info("Hello!")
 

  [...]
```

Should produce `[Login] Hello!`

My custom hook, then, needs the name `Login`:

```
export const useLogger = () => {
  // "this" is undefined
  const loggerName = ??????
  return logManager.getLogger(loggerName);
};
```

In the context of a class, what I'm looking for is something like `this.constructor.displayName`. However, a React hook does not have `this` set, and I cannot seem to find documentation on obtaining reference to the functional component's context.

—-

**Edit**: I would prefer not to pass any arguments and not to add a bunch of boiler plate. My goal is that the `useLogging()` function will survive component refactoring, and not rely upon the developer to provide a "correct" name.

Comment: You could change the signature of the custom hook to take a namespace argument for logging, `const useLogger = namespace => ...`. Functional components are instanceless and hooks aren't generally aware of their caller (AFAIK).

Comment: I should have specified — if you try to use `useHistory` with a non-component, it will throw an error. This implies that hooks can be context-aware, IMO. I'm aware I could pass a name, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, this was merely an example of the point. Though admittedly, it may be happening at the Typescript level (?), and therefore not accessible at runtime.

Comment: Yes, react strips out a bunch of compile & runtime checks in production builds as they are mostly there for the development experience.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a couple other ways that I can think of that you could use. The first and the simplest the one Drew suggested in the comment, which is to simply pass the logging name as an argument:

```js
const useLogger = (name: string) => {
  return logManager.getLogger(name)
}

const Login: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const log = useLogger('Login')
  // ...
}
```

You could also obtain the name via `.displayName` or `.name`. Notice that `.name` refers to `Function.name`, which, if you're using webpack, will probably be minified in a production build so you'll end up with names like "t" or "s" etc. If you need the same name as in your component, you can assign [`displayName`](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging) and let the hook take care of it:

```
const useLogger = (component: React.ComponentType<any>) => {
  const name = useLogger(component.displayName || component.name);
  return logManager.getLogger(name);
}

const Login: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const log = useLogger(Login)
}
Login.displayName = 'Login';
```

---

If you're okay with passing a name to `useLogger`, but don't want to set `displayName` every time, you could use something like [`ts-nameof`](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof) which aims to give you a `nameof` operator [like in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof):

```
const useLogger = (name: string) => {
  return logManager.getLogger(name)
}

const Login: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const log = useLogger(nameof(Login))
  // ...
}
```

The upside here is that the name will survive auto-renames. This requires some bundler or Babel configuration. I haven't tested how minification affects this, but there's three different flavors of `ts-nameof` (at the time of writing) which you can use:

- a compile-time transform for the TypeScript compiler: [ts-nameof](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof/tree/master/packages/ts-nameof)
- a Babel macro: [ts-nameof.macro](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof/tree/master/packages/ts-nameof.macro)
- a Babel plugin: [babel-plugin-ts-nameof](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-ts-nameof)

Pick the first one that matches your build pipeline.

---

Alternatively, if the logger isn't *component-specific*, but *module-specific*, you could make a factory for the hook, and initialize it once at the top of your module:

```
const makeUseLogger = (name: string) => () => {
  return logManager.getLogger(name)
}

// in your module

const useLogger = makeUseLogger('Module name')

const Login: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const log = useLogger()
  // ...
}
```

As an extension of this, if the logger itself doesn't actually need to be a hook (doesn't use other hooks or need props etc.), just make a logger for your module at the top level directly:

```
const log = logManager.getLogger('Module name')

const Login: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  log.info('hello')
}
```

---

Additionally, if you don't mind your project's directory structure leaking into a production build, you can use a webpack trick:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  node: {
    __filename: true
  }
}
```

and then

```
const log = logManager.getLogger(__filename)
```

In a file whose path is `/home/user/project/src/components/Login.ts`, and the webpack *context* is `/home/user/project`, the `__filename` variable will resolve to be `src/components/Login.ts`.

Although, this will probably require you to create a typedef e.g. `globals.d.ts` where you declare the `__filename` global for Typescript:

```
declare global {
  __filename: string;
}
```

**Note**: this will *not* work if your build target is `umd`.

---

As a side-note, technically, if you for some reason don't want to pass any args to `useLogging`, you *could* use the **deprecated** `Function.caller` property, e.g.

```
function useLogging() {
  const caller = (useLogging.caller as React.ComponentType<any>);
  const name = caller.displayName || caller.name;
  console.log(name);
  return logManager.getLogger(name);
}

const Login: React.FC<Props> = () => {
   const log = useLogging()
   // ...
}
```

However, that property is **deprecated** so you'll have to clean that up sooner or later, so **don't do that in production code**.

Comment: Woof. My goal here was to avoid passing any arguments, or adding tons of boilerplate :( It seemed to me that it must be possible to get the name of the component, because if you try to use `useHistory()` (for example) anywhere expect in a component, it will tell you "Blah is not a react component." The `__filename` approach seems a close second best, because at least it will survive refactoring... and I can always parse out the paths to get the filename without directory/extension.

Comment: @ZaneClaes That's probably ESLint and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` which gives you the name in the error. ESLint parses your source code directly, so it gets access to the function name from there. If you use a hook in a class component, the error that React throws doesn't mention the component's name, but just highlights the line from the error's stack trace. So yes, I guess technically you could parse the name from `new Error().stack`, but that property is nonstandard and again, will be a minified name in a typical production build.

Comment: Yeah... that's a shame. `new Error().stack` would also be classic "using exceptions as control flow," which is never a good plan :(

Comment: @ZaneClaes Yeah, it would also be slow. I added one other way using `ts-nameof` - I think it'll probably be the best middle-ground.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the thoroughness. And my backend is in C#, so in jives well with how I do things there.